# Error al obtener el m3u8 por medio de PHP

Tags: php

Estoy con un codigo PHP, que se pone un enlace m3u8, y se puede reproducir de manera local, pero me está dando problema, funciona, obtiene el enlace, pero, si adentro del m3u8 está el link completo lo reproduce.
Por ejemplo. Un video m3u8 que está formado asi:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:3139
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-11T00:09:03.041000+00:00
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="/T3RVZG13aGNxV1BkS2VN/QjgvQmdTbWVLU0pmeHNR/L0ZPeXExU0t2OGQzVzFq/MVdpVWxtZEhJRGRzWTVS/ZWhxUDl3ZGMrb2hmU2xa/SitWZlRoOHRSOFhNN0Jm/NnpDZVJGYTFKNUs2cFdD/M3NPSFhkWEhoV0J6ZmUr/bkhlK2NpbzJBdnF2dlNt/dXhGSExKeVdxckZLWG00/K1RHVklEMml1SFdCdkUx/ek9qR0lQM0czdGc1bmR2/RjJ4S2JkOWFLRGFoWVJz/OGRnZ2E4WEN5NFE1YXh4/ZVRKc2FDamFuWFpOaUdS/akVrQWw0Wm5tWXNOYkxE/aW10Mk9TaTNpWFRDQ2dU/Wg==",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000188A
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://xxxx.com/auso/slices/eab/d09b16c953aa40c98dd8c513526aca5a/eab562e23f4b45f1be39464d04a8820e/F0000188A.ts
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="/T3RVZG13aGNxV1BkS2VN/QjgvQmdTbWVLU0pmeHNR/L0ZPeXExU0t2OGQzVzFq/MVdpVWxtZEhJRGRzWTVS/ZWhxUDl3ZGMrb2hmU2xa/SitWZlRoOHRSOFhNN0Jm/NnpDZVJGYTFKNUs2cFdD/M3NPSFhkWEhoV0J6ZmUr/bkhlK2NpbzJBdnF2dlNt/dXhGSExKeVdxckZLWG00/K1RHVklEMml1SFdCdkUx/ek9qR0lQM0czdGc1bmR2/RjJ4S2JkOWFLRGFoWVJz/OGRnZ2E4WEN5NFE1YXh4/ZVRKc2FDamFuWFpOaUdS/akVrQWw0Wm5tWXNOYkxE/aW10Mk9TaTNpWFRDQ2dU/Wg==",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000188B
#EXTINF:4.0960,
```

Como ven, dentro del m3u8, tiene un archivo .ts, que es un link, en este caso no hay problema, pero si el m3u8 adentro solo tiene el archivo (se supone que solo funciona en x web) no se puede, e intenté pero no puede hacer para que haga referencia a su dominio (que es el que aloja el m3u8) y no al mio.
Por ejemplo:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:559
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXTINF:8.340,
1605053587667.jar
```

Como ven, el archivo `jar` no tiene el dominio, entonces con el codigo PHP, toma que ese archivo está en mi dominio, y yo tendría que hacer, que tome el link que si tiene ese archivo.
Aca mi codigo:

```
<?php

$server = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}";
$options = array(
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36",
          );
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header' => $options,
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

if(isset($_GET['jar'])){
  echo file_get_contents($_GET['jar'], false, $context);
  exit();
}

$data = '';
while ($data == '') $data = file_get_contents('http://www.xxx.cz/xxx/xxx/index.m3u8', false, $context);
echo str_replace('URI="', 'URI="'.$server.'?jar=', $data);
 
?>
```

Adentro de $data está todo, asi que independientemente no puedo agregar el dominio ahi.

Answer (score 0):

En `$_GET['jar']` estás recibiendo una url a donde está alojado el archivo `.m3u8`.

```
$url = $_GET['jar'];
```

Esa es la ruta que deberías usar para referenciar al `.jar`.
Primero, tenemos que obtener la ruta sin el nombre del archivo:

```
$dominio = dirname($url);
```

Y luego, podemos reemplazar en `$data` todas las líneas que terminen en `.jar` agregándole este dominio:

```
$data = preg_replace('/^[^#:\v][^:\v]*\.jar$/mi', "$dominio/$0", $data);
```

- `^[^#:\v]` coincide con el primer caracter de la línea (cualquiera menos `#`, `:` o saltos de línea).
- `[^:\v]*` coincide con el resto de la línea (cualquier caracter menos `:` o saltos de línea).
- `\.jar$` coincide si la línea termina en `.jar`

Te quedaría algo como:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:559
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXTINF:8.340,
http://url.com/ruta/del/archivo/1605053587667.jar
```

---

---

**Código**

```
$url = $_GET['jar'];
$dominio = dirname($url);
$data = preg_replace('/^[^#:\v][^:\v]*\.jar$/mi', "$dominio/$0", $data);
```

Comment: Lo ajusté todo como dices, pero no funciona, sigue apareciendo el archivo solo, y esto hace que lo tome como si estuviera en mi dominio. Lo que vi, es que en ningun lado pongo la ruta de donde está realmente.

Comment: ¿No la estás obteniendo como parámetro en `$_GET['jar']` con la url del archivo? Lo que en el código pusiste como `'http://www.xxx.cz/xxx/xxx/`, ¿de dónde sale? ... Y tenés que modificar a `$data` **luego** de haber leido el contenido del archivo

Comment: Como es, por ejemplo, con lo que pasé arriba, por lo menos, como quedaría.

Comment: @Mati esta es la forma en que podés reemplazar en `$data` para que cambie los `.jar` sin URL para que tengan una url absoluta... La idea es que tomes esto y lo adaptes a tu código

Comment: Gracias, pero como voy a adaptar algo que no se donde va, o que tengo que hacer con eso.

Comment: **LUEGO** de que ya tengas el contenido asignado en `$data`

Comment: Ahi probé y sigue igual, gracias igual.